# Creating a scrolling newsfeed with React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add a news feed to my React app.
I have a txt with news:

```
Latest news:
bla bla bla

Older news:
bla bla bla

Oldest news:
bla bla bla
```

I would like it to look like a box with the news as a text which would be scrolling inside the box, from the top down. That is, the latest news would apear first and that it would scroll so the older news would show.

I was looking for some npm React package specific for this task but didn't find anything...

Is there any known packages that do that? If not, is this easily achievable using React?

Answer (score 0):

It is highly unlikely you'll find a package that suits your needs because,

1. The package might be expecting data in a different way than you are providing.
2. Adding subtle feature might/might not be easy.

Otherwise, a feed feature is pretty easy to implement. Call the api which provides you with the required data, map and parse through it. Once you are at the end of your fields, call the api once again with the new offsets and append the result to your existing feed data structure.

Comment: You  need to define a fixed height to the component you are rendering it in. So, once it gets beyond the height of the component, an overflow occurs and you can scroll it.